# Difference between FirstOrDefault() and FirstOrDefault<MyClass>()?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

If `FirstOrDefault()` does not return a value, then the return value is null, what comes back from `FirstOrDefault<MyClass>()` and which is best practice?

What are some scenarios where it would be better to use `FirstOrDefault<MyClass>()` because it seems that if your call does not return anything, it is best to return null and check for that.

Comment: So what happens if you take an empty collection and call `FirstOfDefault()` on it? It's a one-liner to see.

Comment: with the generic arguments, you are just being more specific for information the compiler provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `FirstOrDefault()`, any time you see it the compiler is filling in the `<>` for you. The actual signature is

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

The `IEnumerable<MyClass>` you are calling it on provides the information to be filled in.

Comment: Exactly, because the method `FirstOrDefault()` returns `default(TSource)` and not just `null` it needs to infer the type. So even if you don't explicitly name the type, the compiler figures it out.